# Configure dispatcher on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: dispatcher, aem

Am not able to get dispatcher working on my Ubuntu machine, following is the error that I get after apache restart

Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/apache2/conf.d/dispatcher.any:
Invalid command '/farms', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.

Am using the default dispatcher.any file without any changes.

I've enabled the dispatcher module as below:

```
LoadModule dispatcher_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/dispatcher-apache2.2-4.1.4.so

<IfModule disp_apache2.c>
        # location of the configuration file. eg: 'conf/dispatcher.any'
        DispatcherConfig conf.d/dispatcher.any

        # location of the dispatcher log file. eg: 'logs/dispatcher.log'
        DispatcherLog    /var/log/apache2/dispatcher.log

        # log level for the dispatcher log
        # 0 Errors
        # 1 Warnings
        # 2 Infos
        # 3 Debug
        DispatcherLogLevel 3

        # if turned to 1, the dispatcher looks like a normal module
        DispatcherNoServerHeader 0

        # if turned to 1, request to / are not handled by the dispatcher
        # use the mod_alias then for the correct mapping
        DispatcherDeclineRoot 0

        # if turned to 1, the dispatcher uses the URL already processed
        # by handlers preceeding the dispatcher (i.e. mod_rewrite)
        # instead of the original one passed to the web server.
        DispatcherUseProcessedURL 0

        # if turned to 1, the dispatcher does not spool an error
        # response to the client (where the status code is greater
        # or equal than 400), but passes the status code to
        # Apache, which e.g. allows an ErrorDocument directive
        # to process such a status code.
        DispatcherPassError 0
</IfModule>
```

Can anyone please help me out in resolving the issue?

Thanks,
-- Pawan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `dispatcher.any` out of `conf.d/` and into `conf/` and update `DispatcherConfig`

What happens is, when apache starts up it goes through the `conf.d` directory and tries to load the files contained within as apache configuration files. The `dispatcher.any` file is not an apache configuration file and cannot be loaded as such. This causes the syntax error on the first non-comment line of the file.

Comment: Yes, I got it working yesterday but your answer explains it better. Thanks